# USB drive kaput!

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive

`syslog` reports that `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1` has been inserted, neither `fsck` nor `photorec` see it.

Is there some other means to recover the files on this device?

Comment: So what kernel says? What do you see when you insert the drive and do `dmesg | tail -n20`?

Comment: On what block device are you running `photorec`? BTW Why `photorec` and not `testdisk`? Despite all of this, you should make a bitstream copy before any other attempt!

Comment: dmesg reports attempted insertion of Scandisk stick but assigns no device name, e.g., /dev/sdb,  Thus, programs needing a device name, testdisk say, don't see it.  Likewise with fsck, etc.  What to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a normal external harddrive, remove it from the case and connect it using SATA. This will help both if the USB bridge chip is damaged (because you then won't use it) but also when the problem lies with the drive itself: many USB bridge chips handle failing harddrives badly (for example often drive read timeouts lead to the entire USB device disappearing and reappearing).

Comment: It's a USB stick, dmesg sees it, but no device name (e.g., /dev/sdb) is assigned and programs needing a device target (so far as I know) don't see it.  There's lots I don't know, however!  Suggestions welcome.